# using css after how do i show two lines one small one large next to each other under heading

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

how do i make this split underline using CSS

here is what i have tried but it gets full line

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  width: 3rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Key Offerings for You</h2>
```

Comment: You can also use the `before` pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

I made you a SVG. Just pasted it as a background-image in the`::after` pseudo-element and center-align it below it. You can color it with the `fill` property and resize it without any loss of the quality.

```html
<svg width="120" height="8" viewBox="0 0 120 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="40" width="80" height="8" rx="4" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect width="20" height="8" rx="4" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will actually stay centered on the text. You may have to tweak some values to get it how you like.

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
h2::after, h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  bottom: -10px;
  background: orange;
}
h2::after {
  width: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(calc(-50% - 20px));
}
h2::before {
  width: 40px;
  left: calc(50% + 10px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<br>
<h2>Really long heading</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, after I let you play with left and width to make it as you wish:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

/*h2::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  width: 3rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}*/
h2::before, h2::after {
    content: "";
    width: 1%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
}
h2::after {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: orange;
    left: 24%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Key Offerings for You</h2>
```

Comment: This isn't responsive to the text that is inside, if the text changes it will be misaligned.

Comment: @dantheman 1st he did not ask for Responsive, 2nd responsive is easy to make by setting a width to container, 3rd it is a header so it will not change so much and he did not specify for having specialy centered. but your solution is also a good option.

Comment: Responsiveness is implied as it's a core component of good frontend development. Hard coding values like this is never good practice. The heading could be reused throughout the site with varying amounts of text.